# ES6 - Is there a way to filter deeply nested object by a search term

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an object that has multiple keys with varying levels of depth. I am looking to create a new object with only the nodes that match the search term:

Desired search term: 'my search term'.

Original object:

```
{
    grandParent1: {
        parent1: {
            child1: {
                grandChild1: {
                    name: 'my search term'
                },
                grandChild2: {
                    name: 'not my search term'
                },
                grandChild3: {
                    name: 'not my search term either'
                },
            },
            child2: {
                grandChild1: {
                    name: 'my search term'
                },
                grandChild2: {
                    name: 'not my search term'
                }
            }
        },
        parent2: {
            child1: {
                name: 'my search term'
            }
        },
        parent3: {
            name: 'my search term'
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for:

```
{
    grandParent1: {
        parent1: {
            child1: {
                grandChild1: {
                    name: 'my search term'
                }
            },
            child2: {
                grandChild1: {
                    name: 'my search term'
                }
            }
        },
        parent2: {
            child1: {
                name: 'my search term'
            }
        },
        parent3: {
            name: 'my search term'
        }
    }
}
```